# Styling navigation menu with CSS3

Tags: html, css, user-interface, navigation

Please take a look at [this nav menu](http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/DBzSD/1/)

Currently it looks like below

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve, is result shown below (I made this on Photoshop)

[image]

Is that possible to get this result with CSS3? If yes please help me. Can't figure out, how to get this result

Comment: Are the characters 5 and 10 displayed as text? I think you'll have to make the background-image so that the triangle is included.

Comment: Why not use the `::before` and/or `::after` pseudo elements to display the text, since you're already using them?

Comment: @DavidThomas dont know how, to get this

Comment: @DavidThomas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870009/styling-navigation-menu-with-css3/10871699#10871699 you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go

http://jsfiddle.net/DBzSD/11/

I have used CSS pseudo elements to display them you can replace with normal elements if you want but that wont be a very wise choice.

Secondly i have used the data-attribute to show the value of the number , you can dynamically change the number with very minimal amount of javascript and that will automatically change the numbers shown in the box :-)

Hope that helps ..

Sorry i failed to find out your hover effects :-(

Answer (score 0):

I can't find where you specify the border on the hover event, but I would make the green line part of the div, and then use the triangle as an image inside the div.

Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Neograph734/DBzSD/8/

Comment: Thx for fast reply but. The part that I can't figure out is, how to get this work with triangle:))

Comment: You can draw shapes with css, but that is rather tricky. In my example I used a square image. Just replace that link to a triangle image ;)

Comment: .count {
    padding: 9px 0;
     float: right;        
    background: url('http://mathforum.org/alejandre/green.square.gif') no-repeat center right;
}
All at the bottom ;)

Comment: It's not even near to the result which I want to achieve